# Por que da error en el name y en true

Tags: odoo, pycharm, model-view-controller

estoy haciendo este modelo pero me marca error en name = fields.Char y en la ultima linea despues del parentecis estoy hacinedo el modelo en PyCharm y por esos errores no me deja ver mis modificaciones en odoo

Adjunto codigo:

```
'''# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  from odoo import models, fields, api


 class Visit(models.Model):
 _name = 'custom_crm.visit'
 _description = 'Visit'

  name = fields.Char(string='Descripcion')
  customer = fields.Char(string='Cliente')
  date = fields.Datetinme(string='Fecha')
  type = fields.Selections([('P', 'Presencial'),('W', 'WhatsApp'),('t','Telefonico')], string='Tipo', required=True)
  done = fields.Boolean(string='Realizada', readonly=True)'''
```

en este codigo donde dice name = manda error en la especidficacion de name y tambien manda error al cerrar el parentecis de la ultima linea no se si sean errorres de sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

La identación no está correcta.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Esto de aqui sin identación
from odoo import models, fields, api


class Visit(models.Model):
  # Esto de aqui debe tener 2 ó 4 espacios dependiendo de la configuración
  # que tengas. 
  _name = 'custom_crm.visit'
  _description = 'Visit'

  name = fields.Char(string='Descripcion')
  customer = fields.Char(string='Cliente')
  date = fields.Datetinme(string='Fecha')
  type = fields.Selections([('P', 'Presencial'),('W', 'WhatsApp'),('t','Telefonico')], string='Tipo', required=True)
  # Este campo tiene ''' al final. Hay que quitarlo.(Supongo que es error al editar aqui en SO'''
  done = fields.Boolean(string='Realizada', readonly=True)
```